# DNS server keeps changing from Auto to Manual

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, dns, tcpip

A friend at a company I know has a fairly new Windows 7 laptop. She was complaining that the "internet doesn't work".

After looking at it the first time, in `Wireless > Status > Properties > TCP/IPv4`; **the `DNS server` had changed from `Obtain automatically` to `Manual:192.168.0.1`**:

[image: A]

**Changing this back to `Automatic` brought the interwebz back to life.**

Since then, it happened again. So I changed it back.

Then it happened again. Last night I changed it back to `Automatic` again and ran a virus scan with AVG - it came back clean.

Today, after my friend got the laptop back to the office, it had changed back to `192.168.0.1`; it needs to be on `Automatic` to work.

**Why does the DNS server keep changing from `Automatic` to `Manual`?**

No other wireless machines (XP PC's/Win 7 laptops) are affected.

Comment: I've no idea why it keeps changing, but I'd at least set the static one to a public resolver (e.g. Google's 8.8.8.8) so that until you find the culprit it will work for your friend on auto or on static.  And if you set it to one static choice and it switches to another, that'd tell you you've got something additional going on..

Comment: @MichaelMcNally That's a good idea, I'll get her to change it over to Google, and see if it goes back to 192.168.0.1, and report back. Thanks!

Comment: I know as an alternative, I could change the office network over to use the `192.168.0.x` range, but I'd rather not.

Comment: @MichaelMcNally I just heard back from my friend... turns out, changing the DNS server to `8.8.8.8` doesn't help. It changes back to `192.168.0.1` shortly after.

Comment: Update, over a year on: this still happens!!

Comment: I am seeing this _exact_ same issue happening. I'm going to try uninstalling and reinstalling the Wi-Fi drivers and resetting the TCP/IP stack to see if that fixes it.

Comment: @SamAndrew81 I have the same problem. Few weeks ago I needed to temporarily change the DNS settings on my wireless interface to 8.8.8.8. Later I deleted the address 8.8.8.8 and changed it back to automatic DNS (i.e. from DHCP). Unfortunately it looks like whenever I connect to a different WiFi network it reverts back to the manual setting. Uninstalling Intel software which looked like a WiFi connection manager did not help. Did you manage to resolve the problem?

Comment: @pabouk, yes, I resolved the issue by completely uninstalling the WLAN driver/s and deleting them, then downloading them via Ethernet (wired NIC) and reinstalling them. Be sure you *delete the driver* when you uninstall it from Device Manager.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion SamAndrew81. I did that plus following the instructions here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299357/how-to-reset-tcp-ip-by-using-the-netshell-utility to reset TCP/IP completely, and rebooted. The combination of all of these seems to have fixed it!